# Remove duplicates from parsed CSV array

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I made progress with this based on a previous question, but got one last hurdle.  I have the following data in a csv.

```
this_year   |   minus_one_year  |   minus_two_year  |   minus_three_year
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           |   2               |   2               |   3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
4           |   5               |   5               |   5
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2           |   2               |   2               |   2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
4           |   5               |   4               |   4
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           |   2               |   3               |   3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I read this csv file and now I need produce nodes.  A node contains a node (column heading) along with the value.  So in the above data, you can see that this_year has 3 distinct
values, 1, 2 and 4, so the nodes for this should look like this.

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "name": "1",
      "node": "this_year"
    },
    {
      "name": "2",
      "node": "this_year"
    },
    {
      "name": "4",
      "node": "this_year"
    }
  ]
}
```

The other nodes for the other columns should also be produced.  So far I have this

```
d3.csv('my_csv.csv')
    .then(function(data) {

        let graph = {"nodes" : [], "links" : []};

        graph.nodes = data.reduce(function(acc, line){
            return acc.concat(Object.entries(line).map(function(column){
                return {name: column[0], node: column[1]}
            }))}, [])
            .sort(function (n1, n2) {
                return d3.ascending(n1.name, n2.name);
            });

        console.log('nodes:', JSON.stringify(graph.nodes));

    }).catch(function(error){
});
```

This produces the following

```
[
  {
    "name": "this_year",
    "node": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "this_year",
    "node": "4"
  },
  {
    "name": "this_year",
    "node": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "this_year",
    "node": "4"
  },
  {
    "name": "this_year",
    "node": "1"
  }
]
```

So it has the correct format, but it is outputting the duplicates, it should only contain one each for 1, 2 and 4.  How can I remove these duplicates?  I have looked at reduceRight,
is this something I can use?

Thanks

Comment: Will your values always have the exact same structure and data types? Is it always going to be two strings, with neither including a space?

Comment: Yes, it will always follow that structure.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the `data` array when yor are calling `data.reduce(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that your data is so well groomed, a quick and dirty way is to combine the object's values into strings and make a `Set` out of them. `Set`s, by nature, cannot have duplicates. But at the same time, JavaScript `Set`s can only understand duplicates that are primitive data types (numbers, strings, etc.)

Concat the values, turn it into a `Set`, turn it back into the data structure it was previously.

Please tell me if you find anything confusing about my syntax. I make liberal use of modern JavaScript syntax.

Edit: You can use `Array#filter` to be selective as to what should exist in the array.

```js
const values = [
    {
        "name": "this_year",
        "node": "NA"
    },
    {
        "name": "this_year",
        "node": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "this_year",
        "node": "4"
    },
    {
        "name": "this_year",
        "node": "2"
    },
    {
        "name": "this_year",
        "node": "4"
    },
    {
        "name": "this_year",
        "node": "1"
    }
]
function constructUniques(array) {
    const concattedStringValues = array
           .filter(({node}) => node !== 'NA')
           .map(({name, node}) => `${name} ${node}`)
    const uniqueStrings = new Set(concattedStringValues)
    return [...uniqueStrings].map(concattedVal => {
        const [name, node] = concattedVal.split(' ')
        return {name, node }
    })
}

console.log(constructUniques(values))
```

Comment: That seems to work perfectly, thanks.  One quick question, sometimes, one of the nodes is NA, this comes from the raw data.  Is there any way to remove these entries from the node list?  Thanks

Comment: @kate_hudson What does the value `NA` translate to when in JavaScript? `undefined`, `null`, `'NA'`, `NaN`, etc.

Comment: It is just an NA string.  In the output, it looks like `{
    "name": "minus_two_year",
    "node": "NA"
  }`

Comment: @kate_hudson Always happy to help. Make sure you understand the solution, or else my efforts in explanation of the code will have been in vain. ;). Happy coding